# exit on error from noninteractive R scripts

Tags: r

I have a script that I run from the commandline, like

```
Rscript example.R
```

and I'd like to have it tell me some debugging information when it exits.  If I don't do anything special, if it hits an error, it exits, right there, and I see the error message. So, I added

```
options(error=traceback)
```

and then it gave me not only the error message but the stack at the time of the error, very useful.  Great.

**But** now the script continues on through to the end, tossing up a lot more errors. Why does setting the error change Rscript's behaviour on encountering an error? How do I get it to just exit after the first error, as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah-ha.  The trick is to call `q()`. In the help for `dump.frames`:

```
   options(error = quote({dump.frames(to.file = TRUE); q()}))
```

and to use `traceback` (and `function` instead of `quote`),

```
   options(error = function(){  traceback(); q()} )
```

would do it.